# Error: [Immer] An immer producer returned a new value *and* modified its draft. Either return a new value *or* modify the draft

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit

So, I am making this shopping cart in redux-toolkit, where user can't order more than the quantity available. So, my reducer function is like below for adding to cart.

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import { FoodCartType } from "../../types";

type CartState = {
  cart: FoodCartType[];
};

const initialState: CartState = {
  cart: [],
};

export const foodcartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "foodcart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToCart: (state, action) => {
      console.log(action);
      if (state.cart.length === 0) {
        state.cart.push(action.payload);
      }
      const itemIndex = state.cart.findIndex(
        (item) => item.id === action.payload.id
      );

      if (itemIndex >= 0) {
        return {
          ...state,
          cart: state.cart.map((item) => {
            if (item.id === action.payload.id) {
              return {
                ...item,
                quantity: item.quantity + 1,
                quantity_available: item.quantity_available - 1,
              };
            }
          }),
        };
      } else {
        return {
          ...state,
          cart: [
            ...state.cart,
            {
              ...action.payload.product,
              quantity: 1,
              quantity_available: action.payload.quantity_available - 1,
            },
          ],
        };
      }
    },
  },
});

export const { addToCart } = foodcartSlice.actions;

export default foodcartSlice.reducer;
```

When I click on the dispatch, on the component. I get the following error.

> Unhandled Runtime Error Error: [Immer] An immer producer returned a
> new value *and* modified its draft. Either return a new value *or*
> modify the draft.

So, where I am doing the problem? if I just remove the itemIndex check part, items get pushed into the cart. But, other than that it is giving me this error. How should I rewrite this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your `state.cart.push(action.payload);` line **modifies** the value of `state` and later you `return` a new value.

You are allowed to do one, but not both at once. See [writing reducers with immer](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/usage/immer-reducers)

What you could do here: always modify. That's also far more readable.

```js
export const foodcartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "foodcart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToCart: (state, action) => {
      console.log(action);
// you push later anyways, so you can also delete these lines
//      if (state.cart.length === 0) {
//        state.cart.push(action.payload);
//      }
      const itemIndex = state.cart.findIndex(
        (item) => item.id === action.payload.id
      );

      if (itemIndex >= 0) {
        state.cart[itemIndex].quantity += 1
        state.cart[itemIndex].quantity_available -= 1
      } else {
        state.cart.push({
              ...action.payload.product,
              quantity: 1,
              quantity_available: action.payload.quantity_available - 1,
        })
      }
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: okay just a quick follow up question. So, I fetched my data using RTK query and displayed it in a component. Then in the component, I can add the product in the cart. So, in the cart I can minus the quantity_available, to track the changes. But the UI doesn't get updated of the available quantity. So, I was wondering if I can store the data fetched by RTK query in the redux store,from where I can show the updated data in my component and disable the add to cart button if the available quantity is 0?

Comment: It is generally discouraged. RTK Query assumes that it just is a mirror of data on the server and that the server is always the source of truth and it needs to be in sync with that. So you would have the "true cart" on the server and always send changes to the server and get new state from the server. This will also make things like having the cart synchronous between multiple tabs a lot easier.

Comment: I think as I am using a third party API for that, "true cart" might not be achievable. Have to figure out another way then

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to push duplicate product twice. All you nedd to update your cart state. try below code.

```
export const foodcartSlice = createSlice({
  name: "foodcart",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    addToCart: (state, action) => {
      // no need to push to cart state here
      const itemIndex = state.cart.findIndex(
        (item) => item.id === action.payload.id
      );

      if (itemIndex >= 0) {
        //You need to use bellow code instead
        state.cart.forEach(item => {
         if(item.id === action.payload.id) {
          quantity: item.quantity + 1,
          quantity_available: item.quantity_available - 1,
         }
        });

      } else {
        return {
          ...state,
          cart: [
            ...state.cart,
            {
              ...action.payload.product,
              quantity: 1,
              quantity_available: action.payload.quantity_available - 1,
            },
          ],
        };
      }
    },
  },
});

export const { addToCart } = foodcartSlice.actions;

export default foodcartSlice.reducer;
```